# JMS Serialize Pagination data for KNP paginator bundle

Tags: symfony, solr, jmsserializerbundle, knppaginator

Hi there i am using following bundle for my REST API.

```
 "jms/serializer-bundle" : "0.13.0", /// for serialization
 "nelmio/solarium-bundle" : "2.0.4",// solarium bundle for integration with solr bundle
 "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle" : "2.4.0", // for pagination code
```

now when i try to serialize data using jms serialization for sql query it works fine but when i used solr as a backend and try to deserialize those data i got following errors.

mycode for serialization:

```
$pagination = $paginator->paginate(array($productSearchServices->getSearchClient(), $selectQuery),
                $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
                $this->get('request')->query->get('per_page', 10)/*limit per page*/
            );

            echo $serializer->serialize($pagination, 'json');die;

Resources are not supported in serialized data. Path: Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler -> Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger -> Nelmio\SolariumBundle\Logger -> Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher -> Solarium\Client -> Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Result -> Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Pagination\SlidingPagination
```

Below is the stack trace

```
 in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GraphNavigator.php at line 137  +
at GraphNavigator ->accept (resource, null, object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php at line 140  +
at GenericSerializationVisitor ->visitProperty (object(PropertyMetadata), object(StreamHandler), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GraphNavigator.php at line 227  +
at GraphNavigator ->accept (object(StreamHandler), null, object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php at line 102  +
at GenericSerializationVisitor ->visitArray (array(object(DebugHandler), object(StreamHandler), object(ConsoleHandler)), array('name' => 'array', 'params' => array()), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/JsonSerializationVisitor.php at line 55  +
at JsonSerializationVisitor ->visitArray (array(object(DebugHandler), object(StreamHandler), object(ConsoleHandler)), array('name' => 'array', 'params' => array()), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GraphNavigator.php at line 129  +
at GraphNavigator ->accept (array(object(DebugHandler), object(StreamHandler), object(ConsoleHandler)), null, object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php at line 140  +
at GenericSerializationVisitor ->visitProperty (object(PropertyMetadata), object(Logger), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GraphNavigator.php at line 227  +
at GraphNavigator ->accept (object(Logger), null, object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php at line 140  +
at GenericSerializationVisitor ->visitProperty (object(PropertyMetadata), object(Logger), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GraphNavigator.php at line 227  +
at GraphNavigator ->accept (object(Logger), null, object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php at line 102  +
at GenericSerializationVisitor ->visitArray (array(object(Logger), 'preExecuteRequest'), array('name' => 'array', 'params' => array()), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/JsonSerializationVisitor.php at line 55  +
at JsonSerializationVisitor ->visitArray (array(object(Logger), 'preExecuteRequest'), array('name' => 'array', 'params' => array()), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GraphNavigator.php at line 129  +
at GraphNavigator ->accept (array(object(Logger), 'preExecuteRequest'), null, object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php at line 102  +
at GenericSerializationVisitor ->visitArray (array(array(object(Logger), 'preExecuteRequest')), array('name' => 'array', 'params' => array()), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/JsonSerializationVisitor.php at line 55  +
at JsonSerializationVisitor ->visitArray (array(array(object(Logger), 'preExecuteRequest')), array('name' => 'array', 'params' => array()), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GraphNavigator.php at line 129  +
at GraphNavigator ->accept (array(array(object(Logger), 'preExecuteRequest')), null, object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php at line 102  +
at GenericSerializationVisitor ->visitArray (array(array(array(object(Logger), 'preExecuteRequest'))), array('name' => 'array', 'params' => array()), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/JsonSerializationVisitor.php at line 55  +
at JsonSerializationVisitor ->visitArray (array(array(array(object(Logger), 'preExecuteRequest'))), array('name' => 'array', 'params' => array()), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GraphNavigator.php at line 129  +
at GraphNavigator ->accept (array(array(array(object(Logger), 'preExecuteRequest'))), null, object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php at line 102  +
at GenericSerializationVisitor ->visitArray (array('solarium.core.preExecuteRequest' => array(array(array(object(Logger), 'preExecuteRequest'))), 'solarium.core.postExecuteRequest' => array(array(array(object(Logger), 'postExecuteRequest')))), array('name' => 'array', 'params' => array()), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/JsonSerializationVisitor.php at line 55  +
at JsonSerializationVisitor ->visitArray (array('solarium.core.preExecuteRequest' => array(array(array(object(Logger), 'preExecuteRequest'))), 'solarium.core.postExecuteRequest' => array(array(array(object(Logger), 'postExecuteRequest')))), array('name' => 'array', 'params' => array()), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GraphNavigator.php at line 129  +
at GraphNavigator ->accept (array('solarium.core.preExecuteRequest' => array(array(array(object(Logger), 'preExecuteRequest'))), 'solarium.core.postExecuteRequest' => array(array(array(object(Logger), 'postExecuteRequest')))), null, object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php at line 140  +
at GenericSerializationVisitor ->visitProperty (object(PropertyMetadata), object(EventDispatcher), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GraphNavigator.php at line 227  +
at GraphNavigator ->accept (object(EventDispatcher), null, object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php at line 140  +
at GenericSerializationVisitor ->visitProperty (object(PropertyMetadata), object(Client), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GraphNavigator.php at line 227  +
at GraphNavigator ->accept (object(Client), null, object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php at line 140  +
at GenericSerializationVisitor ->visitProperty (object(PropertyMetadata), object(Result), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GraphNavigator.php at line 227  +
at GraphNavigator ->accept (object(Result), null, object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php at line 102  +
at GenericSerializationVisitor ->visitArray (array('result' => object(Result)), array('name' => 'array', 'params' => array()), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/JsonSerializationVisitor.php at line 55  +
at JsonSerializationVisitor ->visitArray (array('result' => object(Result)), array('name' => 'array', 'params' => array()), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GraphNavigator.php at line 129  +
at GraphNavigator ->accept (array('result' => object(Result)), null, object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php at line 140  +
at GenericSerializationVisitor ->visitProperty (object(PropertyMetadata), object(SlidingPagination), object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GraphNavigator.php at line 227  +
at GraphNavigator ->accept (object(SlidingPagination), null, object(SerializationContext))
in /var/www/API/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/Serializer.php at line 91  +
at Serializer ->serialize (object(SlidingPagination), 'json')
in /var/www/API/src/OfficeBrain/Bundle/SearchEngineBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php at line 118  +
at DefaultController ->searchProductAction ()
at call_user_func_array (array(object(DefaultController), 'searchProductAction'), array())
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2911  +
at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2883  +
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 3022  +
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2303  +
at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
in /var/www/API/web/app_dev.php at line 29  +
```

Comment: I've got the same problem, really annoying. Did you came up with a solution?

Comment: Hi Micahel this problem is come due to logging logic of solarium bundle if you disable those service for nelmio api doc bundle then it wan't come again.